# RDS Serverless - Slow warm up?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm not sure if this is intended or I configured it incorrectly.

I set up my Aurora Serverless PostgreSQL Database to pause after 5 min of inactivity.

Problem is, everytime I try to access it after it has paused, it takes almost 1 minutes for the server to respond for the first time.

Is there any configuration I can do to workaround this other than disabling pausing?

Comment: No. That's the _price_ you pay for the pause/start feature. It's mostly targeted for Dev/UAT instances (i.e. when you stop work in the evening and start again in the morning) or similar usage patterns (i.e. work hours / work days only)

Comment: @Cascader Thank you, I feel stupid now for not researching properly. So I guess if I leave it running 24 hours it will always be more expensive than a equivalent regular RDS?

Comment: That depends on a lot of factors. I suggest you play around with https://calculator.aws/ and try different scenarios. In the meantime, have a look at [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.html#aurora-serverless.use-cases)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes that's one of the main issues when taking advantage from pause but downside it takes time to warm up, you can extend the pause something bigger than five minutes so it will be warm-up always as if you create connection during the time so the timer will reset for inactivity.

> Expand the Additional scaling configuration section. You can disable cluster pausing by unchecking the **Pause compute capacity after consecutive minutes of inactivity checkbox**. Using the hours, minutes, and seconds drop down list boxes, you can change the length of inactivity time until the cluster pauses. By default **your cluster will pause after 5 consecutive minutes of inactivity**.

[configure-connect-serverless-mysql-database-aurora](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/configure-connect-serverless-mysql-database-aurora/)

Select RDS -> DB instance -> database -> configuration
[image]

**24hr is the maximum time**, *you can set something lower then this but if there is one connection at least in 24 hr, it will be warmup always.*

Comment: Heads up for future readers! AWS Just announced they have fixed this issue

Comment: @Mojimi, not completely, the warm up still takes some time and the API calls timeout during that time.